# SQL Server set variable to select statement results seperated by a comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I have this query that i am trying to run The issue is the SET @string = (select statement)

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE
DECLARE @enddate DATE
DECLARE @string INT

SET @startdate = '1/1/2015'
SET @enddate = ' 1/31/2015 23 : 59 : 59 '
SET @string = (
        SELECT String
        FROM mytable2
        WHERE mt2.DATE BETWEEN @startdate
                AND @enddate
        )

SELECT *
FROM mytable MT WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN mytable2 MT2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON MT.ID = MT2.ID
WHERE MT.DATE BETWEEN @startdate
        AND @enddate
    AND MT2.String IN (@String)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Updated to the correct query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `@string` to be a comma-separated list of `String` column values from a particular query.  If so, try this:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(max) = '';

SELECT @string = @string + String + ','
FROM mytable2
WHERE mt2.DATE BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

You'll end up with a trailing comma at the end of the string.  You can cut that off with the `rtrim` function.

Comment: I get this error as my var is an INT
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.
So I need it to list the INT values separated by commas

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the XML method for string concatenation:

```
SET @string = STUFF((SELECT ',' + String
                     FROM mytable2
                     WHERE mt2.DATE BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
                     FOR XML PATH ('concat') TYPE
                    ).VALUE('/concat[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
                    1, 1, '')
```

If your "string" is some other type, then convert it explicitly:

```
SET @string = STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(String as varchar(8000))
                     FROM mytable2
                     WHERE mt2.DATE BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
                     FOR XML PATH ('concat') TYPE
                    ).VALUE('/concat[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
                    1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not do that this way:

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE
DECLARE @enddate DATE

SET @startdate = '1/1/2015'
SET @enddate = ' 1/31/2015 23 : 59 : 59 '

    SELECT 
     *
    FROM mytable MT WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN mytable2 MT2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON MT.ID = MT2.ID
    WHERE
    MT.DATE BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
    AND MT2.String IN (SELECT String
                       FROM mytable2 MT2
                       WHERE MT2.DATE BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```